Evaluate the product of (j^n + 1) for j in a finite field
I stumbled across an exercice and this product came up, with the claim:
$$\displaystyle\prod_{i \in F_{p}}(i^n+1) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        0 & \mbox{if }\; \dfrac{p-1}{\gcd(p-1, n)} \;\mbox{ is even} \\
        2^n  & \mbox{ if not}
    \end{array}
\right.$$
The proof started by assuming that "n|p − 1 since it can be easily proved that the set of n-th powers of the elements of $F_p$ coincides with the set of gcd(p − 1, n)-th powers of the same elements."
And while I do agree that both sets are equals, I don't understand how one can exchange n with the gcd, because "lists" are what is at stake here.
For example, let's imagine that, for some integers a and b, in some field:
$$1^a = 1\\
2^a = 1\\
3^a = 2$$
and
$$1^b = 1\\
2^b = 2\\
3^b = 2$$
The sets here may be equal, $\{1, 2\}$, yet the products aren't the same.
I know my example isn't complete, maybe no such fields exist, yet I feel they forgot an argument to make everything clear, or I'm maybe just missing something.
Could someone explain to me how to finish the line of reasoning? Or do any of you people know an other way to treat this product?
Thanks,

What is $n$ supposed to be?

@CyclotomicField, My bad, I edited my post, n is supposed to be k, I mixed up my variables.

I take it you are concerned about how many times an element of the field appears as  $a^n$ as opposed to as $a^k$, $k=\gcd(p-1,n)$. Those are also equal by a bit of group theory. Consider the mapping $f:x\mapsto x^n$ from $\Bbb{F}_p^*$ to itself. It is a homomorphism (of multiplicative groups). Its kernel has size $k=\gcd(p-1,n)$. It is an observation coming together with the first isomorphism theorem that the preimages of the elements in the image of $f$ are cosets of its kernel. And hence they all have the same number of elements.

(cont'd) I guess that whoever wrote that line felt this was covered by the proof of the fact that sets of $n$th vs $k$th powers are equal. They are even equal as multisets; each element appearing the same number of times. As a small example consider the case of $p=7$, $n=4$, so $k=\gcd(6,4)=2$. The squares in $\Bbb{F}_7$ are $0,1,4,9=2,16=2,25=4,36=1$, and the fourth powers are $0,1,16=2,81=4,256=4,625=2,1296=1$. Here the kernel of the above homomorphism is ${\pm1}$, so its cosets have the form ${\pm x}$. Indeed, $x^4=y^4$ in this field if and only if $x=\pm y$ if and only if $x^2=y^2$.

@JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very much, I understood your argument.

Good. At some point, when you are comfortable with the logic of a solution, feel free to post it as an answer. I am hesitant to do so myself, because I have used the above reasoning already on this site (as have others).  I don't have the time to look for a good thread to refer to right now. And there is the rest of your question as well :-)

I suspect a trick like this gives an answer to the product. Observe that $i^n$, $i\neq0$, ranges over a certain group of roots of unity.

Is the expression being evaluated as an element of $\mathbb F_p$ or as an integer?  As written the right hand side appears to be an integer while the left hand side is (likely) an element of the finite field.  Perhaps the claim is simply a congruence of these values mod $p$.

The LHS is clearly an element of the finite field, while the RHS would be $2^k$ modulo $p$, which would exactly be the same as the element $2$ of the finite field raised to the $k$-th power, wouldn't it ?

With the help of @JyrkiLahtonen, I'll answer my question. We'll also suppose $p\geq 3$.
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a non-negative natural number, $k=\mbox{gcd}(n, p-1)$, and $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^*$ be a non-zero element of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.
We want to show that there are $k$ elements $b \in \mathbb{F}_{p} $ such that $ b^n = a^n$.
If $b^n = a^n$, then $({a*b^{-1})}^n = 1$, we thus look into the kernel of $f:x \mapsto x^n$, which maps $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ into itself.

If $x^n = 1$, then let $g$ be a generator of $ \mathbb{F}_{p}$, we've got $g^{n*j} = 1$ for a $j \in [0; p-1]$, so $p-1 \mid n*j$, so, by Gauss's theorem, $\dfrac{p-1}{k} \mid j$.

And, if $\dfrac{p-1}{k} \mid j$, then $g^{n*j} = 1$.


So there are as many elements $b$ such that $b^n = 1$ than there are integers $j \in [0: p-1]$ such that $\dfrac{p-1}{k} \mid j$ (because $j \mapsto g^j$ it injective on $[0; p-1]$).
There are exactly $k$ such $j's$, namely $\{0,\dfrac{p-1}{k}, 2*\dfrac{p-1}{k}, .., (k-1)*\dfrac{p-1}{k}\}$.
So, $\mid ker(f) \mid = k$
Knowing that, there are exactly $k$ elements whose image is $a^n$ by $f$, they are of the form $a*c$ for $c \in ker(f)$. For people like me, who did a lot of linear algebra, and little general algebra, it's exactly like saying, $f^{-1}(f(a)) = a + ker(f)$ if $f$ is linear.
So, back to our product, we can effectively swap $n$ and $k$, because the sets are the same, and the number of occurrence is the same, as the number of occurence only depends of gcd$(p-1, n) = $ gcd$(p-1, k)$:
$P = \displaystyle\prod_{i \in \mathbb{F}_p^*} i^n + 1 = \displaystyle\prod_{i \in \mathbb{F}_p^*} i^k + 1$
If we let $ t_1, .., t_k $ be the roots of $ X^k+1 $ in some extension of $ \mathbb{F}_p $, we've got:
$ P = \displaystyle\prod_{i \in \mathbb{F}_p^*} \displaystyle\prod_{j = 1}^k (i-t_j) = \displaystyle\prod_{j = 1}^k \displaystyle\prod_{i \in \mathbb{F}_p^*} (t_j-i)$ because $p-1$ is even.
But, we know that $X^{p-1}-1 = \displaystyle\prod_{i \in \mathbb{F}_p^*} (X-i)$, so, $P = \displaystyle\prod_{j = 1}^k (t_j^{p-1}-1) = \displaystyle\prod_{j = 1}^k (({t_j^k})^{\frac{p-1}{k}}-1) = \displaystyle\prod_{j = 1}^k ((-1)^{\frac{p-1}{k}}-1) $
So:
$$\displaystyle\prod_{i \in F_{p}}(i^n+1) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        0 & \mbox{if }\; \dfrac{p-1}{k} \;\mbox{ is even} \\
        2^k  & \mbox{ if not}
    \end{array}
\right.$$
Because if  $\dfrac{p-1}{k} \;\mbox{ is odd}$, then $k$ must be even because $p-1$ is even.
